# Keep 3D effect for push button when changing background-color

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to apply a 3D effect to my push button, as shown below. The default button style has some 3D effect but when I apply the `background-color` via `setStyleSheet("background-color: green");`, it looks a bit dull.

[image]

How do I *retain* the 3D effect of the button when I apply different colors?

Comment: Show us how you would like the green button to look! (The best option to do this, will probably be to express it in form of a style sheet)

Comment: A good starting point for a green button style seems to be here: [Qt Style Sheets Examples #Customizing QPushButton in: Qt Widgets 5.14.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the way to access a style sheet is calling `setStyleSheet` which overwrites the complete style sheet, there should be a way to

- get the current style sheet ([`QWidget::stylesheet()`](https://forum.qt.io/topic/27246/solved-get-style-from-qpushbutton/3))
- modify it ([`QString::replace()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-11)) and
- re-apply it (`setStyleSheet()`)